# Converting Markov Chain Python Script to PHP. Not sure of what some of the equivalent functions are in PHP

Tags: php, python, markov-chains

I've seen this Markov Chain gibberish detector written in response to [another question on Stackoverflow](https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector) and I would like to convert it to PHP, I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but I am confused over portions of the Python code that I have no knowledge of. I've looked at the python docs but it confuses me even further.

1. What is the PHP equivalent of yield?

   ```
   def ngram(n, l):
   """ Return all n grams from l after normalizing """
   filtered = normalize(l)
   for start in range(0, len(filtered) - n + 1):
       yield ''.join(filtered[start:start + n])
   ```
2. What exactly is xrange? There is a PECL extension, however I would prefer a pure PHP implementation? Would this be possible?

   ```
   counts = [[10 for i in xrange(k)] for i in xrange(k)]

   for i, row in enumerate(counts):
   s = float(sum(row))
   for j in xrange(len(row)):
       row[j] = math.log(row[j] / s)
   ```
3. What does assert do? Is it the equivalent of throwing an Exception?

   ```
   assert min(good_probs) > max(bad_probs)
   ```
4. Python Pickle, is that essentially serialize?

   ```
   pickle.dump({'mat': counts, 'thresh': thresh}, open('gib_model.pki', 'wb'))
   ```

Thanks for any help.

---

Edit: typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*1. What is the PHP equivalent of yield?*

There is no equivalent to `yield` in PHP. [`yield`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt) is used in generator functions - a special class of function that returns a result but retains its state.

For example:

```
def simple_generator(start=0, end=100):
    while start < end:
        start += 1
        yield start
gen = simple_generator()
gen() # 1
gen() # 2
gen() # 3
```

You can do something similar in PHP like so:

```
class simple_generator {
    private $start;
    private $end;
    function __construct($start=0, $end=100) {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }
    function __call() {
        if($this->start < $this->end) {
            $this->start++;
            return $start;
        }
    }
}
gen = simple_generator();
gen(); // 1
gen(); // 2
```

*2. What exactly is xrange?*

[`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) behaves just like `range`, but uses a generator function. This is a performance tweak for working with very large lists or when memory is tight.

*3. What does assert do? Is it the equivalent of throwing and Exception?*

Yes. Beware - it is not the same as PHP's [`assert`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) - which is a really *fun* vector for attacks on your software.

*4. Python Pickle, is that essentially serialize?*

Yes.

Comment: In regards to your answer for question 1. I see that you could also use the static $start = 0; value set within a php function.

Comment: @buggedcom: Regarding `static` for generators: No, you can't use `static` for this. That is, unless you want to restrict yourself to having only a *single, not reset-able* instance *for the whole process*. The few lines saved are rarely, if ever, worth that.

Answer (score 1):

1. xrange returns an iterator. This is different from range which returns a list. Both behave mostly in the same fashion so just use it like you use range.
2. Yes
3. Yes

Comment: @buggedcom: Source code of the answer implies yes (first item is numbered 2). For better or for wrose, markdown ignores such numbering "errors" and just displays `1..3` instead of `2..4`.